# How to set dateFormat for jQuery UI datepicker according to server date format?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using ASP.NET MVC and working with two servers. On first server (for testing) date format is set to `dd.mm.yy`, but on second - `mm/dd/yy`. The question is: is it possible to customize dateFormat for jQuery UI datepicker according to server date format where site is working?

Rendering date on view:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(p=>Model.myDate)%>
```

Javascript code example:

```
$('#myDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    onSelect: function (dateText) { doSomething(); },
    onClose: function () { doAction(); }
})
```

Is it possible to replace strongly typed `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'` with something that will format date according to server date format? And if 'yes' - how to do it?

For now, I am using some temporary solution:

```
$('#myDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: $("#myDate").val().indexOf('/') > 0 ? 'mm/dd/yy' : 'dd.mm.yy',
    onSelect: function (dateText) { doSomething(); },
    onClose: function () { doAction(); }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enforce the format on your control i.e.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDate, String.Format("{0:dd/M/yy}", Model.YourDate),
  new { @class = "datepicker datepicker-init" })
```

jQuery UI takes a slightly different date format i.e `dd/mm/y` not `mm/dd/yy` as in your question.

So this would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y'
        });

</script>
```

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/Fa8Xx/1376/

If that is no good you could determine the format, and set it on your ViewModel i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat: '@Model.MyDateFormat'
        });

</script>
```

**Update**

Ok, to determine if the date has a forwards slash you could do it as follows:

Create a string extension, which replaces them either way;

```
public static string ContainsForwardSlashReplace(this string aString)
{
    return aString.Contains("/") ? aString.Replace("/",".") : aString.Replace(".","/");
}
```

Then call this on your formatted date in your controller, for both your returned date and your jQueryUI format.

Here is a simple console example of a before and after:

```
var aDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
    // Change below to the oposite that is returned from above to test to other way
    //var aDate = "23/01/2014";
    var jqueryUiFormat = "dd/mm/y";
string newDate = aDate.ContainsForwardSlashReplace();
string newjQueryUiFormat = jqueryUiFormat.ContainsForwardSlashReplace();
Console.WriteLine("Original Date: {0}", aDate);
Console.WriteLine("Replaced Date: {0}", newDate);
Console.WriteLine("Original jQueryFormat : {0}", jqueryUiFormat);
Console.WriteLine("Replaced jQueryFormat: {0}", newjQueryUiFormat);
```

The final piece is to add both the formated date and jQuery ui date format to your model and output it as I describe above.

**UPDATE** *(by question author)*

Seems there are **no solution what I am looking for**. So this one will be marked as solution. For more - see comments.

Comment: I clarified the question (add example of date input rendering). As for the _jQuery UI takes a slightly different date format i.e `dd/mm/y` not `mm/dd/yy` as in your question._ - I try format `mm/dd/y` and its work.

Comment: Speaking of the `@Model.MyDateFormat` - its can be good idea.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Sorry, what is the part that is missing?

Comment: I just wanted to keep simple `<%=Html.EditorFor(p=>Model.myDate)%>` and set server date format for datepicker (if it is possible).

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry but I've not found a work around for that, which doesn't include the TextBoxFor for other than the above included in a custom editor for template which renders the TextBoxFor underneath. Hopefully someone will have the full answer for you. Good luck. :)

Comment: Anyway, really appreciate the help.